# How do I create a fixed position div inside a containing div?

Tags: html, css

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E2gYN/1/)

**How can I get the 'Tree' to be positioned at the top inside the second row?**

I have read some sources on this, some claiming that fixed is positioned relative to its outer container, other relative to the browser window. On position:absolute, I've read that it's relative to the browser window, but [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_position.asp) claim that it's relative to the first positioned element. All of this is making my head a little fuzzy, and despite playing around with both properties I have not been able to really get my head around this.

Comment: I would really try to avoid using tables for you layout. You're really going to strugle to get the positioning effects you want without using divs and CSS for layout

Comment: To anyone attempting to answer this question: check your answer in Firefox.

Comment: @Alex: Thanks for your comment, I guess you are right, but for the sake of learning I'd like to struggle with this for a while.
@thirtydot: Care to fill me in on what your comment means?

Comment: @Emil with all due respect, you'd be best leaving this method alone. Learn correctly from the start. This is like learning to drive on the wrong side of the road.

Comment: +1 Alex Thomas is right, though it's true that you also learn by making it wrong... all in all, the really important thing is that you understand what you are doing and not just copy code here and there without using your head.

Comment: @Emil: It looks like nobody took my advice. Check your "Working JSFiddle based on accepted answer." with Firefox - it doesn't work. Look where "Tree" is.

Comment: @Alex&Jose: Alright, thanks for the input guys. I'll def learn to drive on the right side of the road!
@thirtydot: Ahh, now I see. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

position:fixed always refer to the browser window. A fixed positioned element won't change it's position when scrolling the browser window.

If you want a relatively positioned element inside another element, you must give the container (parent) element a `position:relative;`, and the element inside it a `position:absolute;`. This way the absolutely positioned element coordinates will be based on the parent (relatively positioned) element.

Also, when trying to use absolute and relative positioning for a layout, it's better not to use tables.

**Update**

The absolute positioned element will search through the DOM tree, looking for the nearest ancestor that is positioned as well. If it finds none, it will position itself relative to the browser window. – Justus Romijn

**Update 2**

just give `position:relative;` to the td containing the absolute positioned element, like this
http://jsfiddle.net/E2gYN/5/

Comment: The absolute positioned element will search through the DOM tree, looking for the nearest ancestor that is positioned as well. If it finds none, it will position itself relative to the browser window.

Comment: Thanks Jose and Justus for the thorough explanation. I have updated my question with a working JSFiddle.

Comment: I update my answer with a working example showing you what I meant by absolute positioned element inside a relative positioned one. Hope it helps you in your learnings.

Comment: Here is and example of what these guys have been saying. http://jsfiddle.net/htU7B/

Comment: @Jose: Thanks! 
@Lollero: Thanks for that aswell.

Comment: @Emil heres by the way example of how nested positions work http://jsfiddle.net/htU7B/1/